# How do I add a column where I interpret another column as a time period?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Lets say I have the following data frame called `example`:

```
ID     amount_ID    
3      1
3      2
3      3
3      4
3      5
9      1
9      2
9      3
9      4
3      1
3      2
3      3
```

As you can see when a new `ID` starts the `amount_ID` starts counting from 1 again.

How can I add a column where I want a timespan of 100 for the `amount_ID` where the last `amount_ID` is 100. It should look like this:

```
ID     amount_ID   timespan
3      1           20         (because 1*100/5=20)
3      2           40         (because 2*100/5=40)
3      3           60         
3      4           80
3      5           100        (because 5*100/5=100)
9      1           25         (because 1*100/4=25)
9      2           50
9      3           75
9      4           100
3      1           33.33      (because 1*100/3=33.33)
3      2           66.67
3      3           100
```

I added some calculations so you can understand what I am trying to calculate.IMPORTANT: there are multiple rows with the same ID.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this :

You can either divide `amount_ID` by `max` value of  `amount_ID` for unique occurrence of `ID`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, timespan := amount_ID/max(amount_ID) * 100, rleid(ID)]
df
#    ID amount_ID timespan
# 1:  3         1     20.0
# 2:  3         2     40.0
# 3:  3         3     60.0
# 4:  3         4     80.0
# 5:  3         5    100.0
# 6:  9         1     25.0
# 7:  9         2     50.0
# 8:  9         3     75.0
# 9:  9         4    100.0
#10:  3         1     33.3
#11:  3         2     66.7
#12:  3         3    100.0
```

Divide by number of rows in each group.

```
setDT(df)[, timespan := amount_ID/.N * 100, rleid(ID)]
```

Divide by last value of `amount_ID`

```
setDT(df)[, timespan := amount_ID/last(amount_ID) * 100, rleid(ID)]
```

---

We can use the same in `dplyr` as well.

```
library(dplyr)
```

1. Divide by max

   ```
   df %>% 
      group_by(gr = rleid(ID)) %>% 
      mutate(timespan = amount_ID/max(amount_ID) * 100)
   ```
2. Divide by number of rows

   ```
   df %>%
     group_by(gr = rleid(ID)) %>%
      mutate(timespan = amount_ID/n() * 100)
   ```
3. Divide by last value

   ```
   df %>%
     group_by(gr = rleid(ID)) %>%
     mutate(timespan = amount_ID/last(amount_ID) * 100)
   ```

Comment: I forgot to mention; there are different rows with the same ID, so this did not work for me. I will change my question accordingly. Because I already tried doing what you did, but since there are multiple scenarios with the same ID, it takes the max amount_ID of everything, but I just want it per situation.

Comment: @Luc Updated the answer. Please check .

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R`

```
with(df, 100 *amount_ID/ave(amount_ID, with(rle(ID), 
          rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = max))
```